# STL: container of container

Tags: c++, stl

I'm noob but as i know it doesnt matter what's data type container contains.
So here is what i'm trying to do:

```
std::deque<list<U32> >     ReqLis;
```

And result of it is next:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'deque' with no type
error: invalid use of '::'
expected ';' before '<' token
```

---

But when instead of it i try to do this:

```
std::list<list<U32> >      ReqList;
```

That's ok..................

Question is am i such great noob or is it compiler fail?
I'm using gcc/g++

Comment: did you `#include <deque>` ?

Comment: you shouldn't use `U32`, but better `std::uint32_t`.

Comment: std::deque<std::list<U32> > ?

Comment: Sorry, i think i'm total noob. I really forgot to include it and dont bother yourself with U32 it's ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you list all the code? The usage of namespaces in your code a bit loose.

The deque in a separate header [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)

```
#include <deque>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard type called U32, but if you #include  (stdint.h for C) you can use std::uint32_t1, a 32 bit unsigned integer, which is (I assume) what you want.

first you should include this header file for user u32

```
   #include <cstdint>

   std::deque<std::list<std::uint32_t>> ReqList;
```

Answer (score 2):

Add following :

```
#include <list>
#include<deque>
#include<stdint.h>
     std::deque<uint32_t> ReqList;



  #include<deque> is for deque data type
  #include<list>  is for list data type
  #include<stdint.h> is for uint32_t (Integer type with a width of exactly 8, 16, 32, or  
                     64 bits.For signed types, negative values are represented using 2's 
                     complement.
```